# PYTHON - imap over TLS

Tags: python, imap, imaplib

I'm creating a mail capture python program. I'm facing an issue with a particular mailbox. Here is the args that works using PHP imap_open:

```
'hostname'      => "{XXX.XX.X.XX:143/imap/tls/novalidate-cert}",
'login'         => "XXXXX",
'password'      => "XXXXX",
```

I'm trying the following with python, but I have the following error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/MailCapture/check_folders.py", line 35, in <module>
    conn.starttls()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/imaplib.py", line 812, in starttls
    server_hostname=self.host)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
    session=session
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
OSError: [Errno 0] Error


hostname = 'XXX.XX.X.X'
port = 143
isSSL = False
login = 'XXXXX'
password = 'XXXXX'

tls = ssl.create_default_context()

try:
    conn = IMAP4(hostname, port)
    conn.starttls(ssl_context=tls)
except (gaierror, IMAP4_SSL.error) as e:
    sys.exit('Error while connecting to ' + hostname + ' on port ' + str(port) + ' : ' + str(e))

try:
    conn.login(login, password)
except (gaierror, IMAP4_SSL.error) as e:
    sys.exit('Error while login to ' + hostname + ' on port ' + str(port) + ' : ' + str(e))
```

I tried without the `conn.starttls()` and I have the following error `Error while login to XXX.XX.X.XX on port 143 : LOGIN command error: BAD [b'Command received in Invalid state.']`

Any ideas, maybe it's works in PHP because of the `novalidate-cert`, is there such an option in Python ?

Thanks

Comment: Does the server actually support STARTTLS?  Is it actualy a TLS (not starttls) server?  Can you turn on debugging so it will print a protocol trace (eg, run imaplib.Debug = 5 before creating any IMAP4 objects)

Comment: No need to imaplib.Debug. I try to connect using telnet on port 143. And before use the LOGIN method, I had to launch STARTTLS command..

Comment: It would still be useful to the rest of us.